# OData and Security in .NET

Tags: .net, security, odata

This great video http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg601461 shows us how to expose OData from any source.

But it is still unclear for me which types of security we can apply to restrict users' access by username, roles and etc. And how we can do it technically.

Could someone explain it please? Thank you!